# 'pickle data was truncated' while loading pickle string in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle

I'm trying to load a pickle string but I get this error:
`pickle data was truncated`

this is a `print()` of the an example of a string (after stripping `\n` and `"`):

```
(iXXX.YYY\nMgr\np1\n(dp2\nS'prop1'\np3\n(lp4\nsS'prop2'\np5\nI10\nsb.
```

The strange thing is when I manually copy this string and try to load the explicit string at the Watch window (PyCharm) its working!

I've tried to encode the string to UTF8, didn't worked. any suggestions?

Comment: How are you loading it in your program? The pickle string seems correct to me (as long as the class `XXX.YYY.Mgr` exists).

Comment: I use `obj = pickle.loads(obj_str)`

Comment: Can you describe the module `XXX.YYY`? Maybe something tricky was happening there?

Comment: I've finally solved it with replace "\\n" with "\n" ,  shame on me, print() is not a good indicator. I'm going to remove this post. Thanks!